# Find all eigenvectors of a linear transformation $T(\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\ c&d\end{pmatrix})=\begin{pmatrix}a&a+b\\ b+c&c+d\end{pmatrix}$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, characteristic-polynomial

Let $$T(\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\ c&d\end{pmatrix})=\begin{pmatrix}a&a+b\\ b+c&c+d\end{pmatrix}$$

Find All eigenvectors (not only the Linear independence) of $T$ over $\mathbb{Z}_5$

My attempted :

First I found Matrix Representation $[T]_B$ when $B$ is the standard basis :

$$[T]_B=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0&0\\ 1&1&0&0\\ 0&1&1&0\\ 0&0&1&1\end{pmatrix}$$

$[T]_B$ is lower triangular matrix then the characteristic polynomial  is $P(\alpha) = (\alpha-1)^4$

and the Eigenvalue are $\alpha_{1,2,3,4}  = 1$

and to find characteristic vectors we need to find the solution space of $[T]_B - I =0$

$\begin{pmatrix}0&0&0&0\\ 1&0&0&0\\ 0&1&0&0\\ 0&0&1&0\end{pmatrix} \rightarrow \begin{pmatrix}1&0&0&0\\ 0&1&0&0\\ 0&0&1&0\\ 0&0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$

the general solution :

$s\begin{pmatrix}1\\ 0\\ 0\\ 0\end{pmatrix}  + t\begin{pmatrix}0\\ 1\\ 0\\ 0\end{pmatrix} + w\begin{pmatrix}0\\ 0\\ 1\\ 0\end{pmatrix}$

and the characteristic vectors are :

$$\left\{\begin{pmatrix}1\\ \:0\\ \:0\\ \:0\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}0\\ \:1\\ \:0\\ \:0\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}0\\ \:0\\ \:1\\ \:0\end{pmatrix}\right\}$$

Is this correct and what the question mean by finding all the characteristic vector (not only the Linear independence) ?

thanks

Comment: I find $$[T]_B\pmatrix{1\\0\\0\\0}=\pmatrix{1\\1\\0\\0}$$ so that $$\pmatrix{1\\0\\0\\0}$$ **isn't** an eigenvector. Also I'm not sure that $[T]_B$ is correct.

Comment: Thats How I found $[T]_B$:
$T\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\ 0&0\end{pmatrix} =  \begin{pmatrix}1&1\\ 0&0\end{pmatrix} = 1 * b_1 + 1 * b_2 + 0*b_3 + 0*b_4 $
$T\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\ 0&0\end{pmatrix} =  \begin{pmatrix}0&1\\ 1&0\end{pmatrix} = 0 * b_1 + 1 * b_2 + 1*b_3 + 0*b_4 $
$T\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\ 1&0\end{pmatrix} =  \begin{pmatrix}0&0\\ 1&1\end{pmatrix} = 0 * b_1 + 0 * b_2 + 1*b_3 + 1*b_4 $
$T\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\ 0&1\end{pmatrix} =  \begin{pmatrix}0&0\\ 0&1\end{pmatrix} = 0 * b_1 + 0 * b_2 + 0*b_3 + 1*b_4 $

Comment: Oh my bad  $T=\begin{pmatrix}a&a+b\\ b+c&c+d\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: and bout the general solution and eigenvector you are correct and  i think that the eigenvector is just $\begin{pmatrix}0\\ \:0\\ \:0\\ 1\end{pmatrix}$?

Comment: You are right, it's $(0,0,0,1)$.